# What special considerations should I consider when I deploy IPv6 with Windows

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, networking, windows-xp, ipv6

We're considering deploying/configuring our Windows machines with IPv6.  Are there any special settings, or quirks that occur with the Windows IPv6 stack?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have machines in your environment that have been cloned you'll want to reset the DUID on each like so:

```
reg delete HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip6\Parameters /f /v Dhcpv6DUID
```

You must disable and re-enable the network connection or reboot the server for the regeneration to take place.

If you don't do this and use DHCPv6 in your environment you'll see address conflicts.

Windows will also silently drop invalid DHCPv6 replies--you can look for them by using something like `netsh trace start scenario=AddressAcquisition capture=yes` and viewing the resulting .etl file in [Microsoft Network Monitor](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=4865).

Answer (score 4):

It depends on which versions of Windows you are using. Windows Vista, Windows 7 and Windows Server 2008 are fine.

Older versions like Windows XP, Windows (Server) 2000 and Windows Server 2003 are not so good. Although Windows XP and Windows Server 2003 have an experimental IPv6 stack they are not good enough for production use. DHCPv6 is not supported for example, and configuring static IPv6 addresses isn't supported either. DNS resolving is only done over IPv4, which might or might not be a problem. Server applications also lack IPv6 configuration options.

Answer (score 0):

Just Make sure your Internal Routers are configured for it.. I have had no problems.